# The best place to store index to data

Tags: c++, oop

I have a text and some index for this text and I need to pass this index to functions which use it.
The index makes sense only with the text it was built for, so it must keep the reference to this text.
At the same time the text could make sense without index and this is the reason I don't want to couple them in the same class like *IndexedText*.

The question is, where is it better to store this index in C++ code? If the index is stored in the std::vector and if I had a chance to inject the reference to the text in this structure, I would be happy, but this is impossible in C++. So, I have to write some kind of a wrapper.

Let's say I end up with the code:

```
template<typename T> 
class Index {
public:    
    const std::string& text;
    const std::vector<T>& index;
};

void render(const Index<int>& index)
{
    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq,index.index.begin(),index.index.end(),
         [](const auto&) { /* some action */ });
}

int main()
{
    const std::string s1 = "abdbc";
    std::vector i1{0,1,2,3,4};

    std::sort(i1.begin(),i1.end(),
        [&](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { /* some predicate for index sorting */ });

    Index index = { s1, i1 };

    render(index);
}
```

My problem is that this *Index* is the same *IndexedText* class and with it I couple text and index and additionally have this redundant constructions like `index.index` which I definitely want to avoid. (I want the code to be read as plain English, so when programmer writes `index.index` I say, please don't slutter or don't repeat yourself).

So, another solution is to make an operator to convert `Index` to `const std::vector<T>&`, but the problem is that C++ can't make implicit conversion for template (I guess, because implicit conversion apply after template argument deduction) so, I will be forced to make this conversion explicit in the client code, which is ugly.

The second approach:

```
template<typename T> 
class Index2 {
public:    
    const std::string& text;
    const std::vector<T>& index;

    operator const std::vector<T>& () const { return index; }
};

void render2(const Index2<int>& index)
{
    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq,index.begin(),index.end(),
        [](const auto&) { /* some action */ });
}

int main()
{
    const std::string s1 = "abdbc";
    std::vector i1{0,1,2,3,4};

    std::sort(i1.begin(),i1.end(),
        [&](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { /* some predicate for index sorting */ });

    Index2 index2 = { s1, i1 };

    render2(index2);
}
```

I can't rely on ranges only, because I need execution policies which are still missing in ranges. So, I need "access" to `begin()`/`end()`.

So the question is, what is the best architecture in C++ to store index reference to avoid code duplication (like writing twice`index.index`) and make in user friendly as much as possible?

**Possible solution**

I found the following solution at the moment:

```
template<typename T> 
class Index2 {
public:    
    const std::string& text;
    const std::vector<T>& index;

    decltype(index.begin()) begin() { return index.begin(); }
    decltype(index.end())   end()   { return index.end(); }
    decltype(index.cbegin()) begin() const { return index.cbegin(); }
    decltype(index.cend())   end() const { return index.cend(); }
};
```

I am still not sure that this is the best approach to the problem.

If in modern C++ both const and non-const versions of the methods could be merged, please let me know in comments.

The combined [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Gq9ooKMar) shows both approaches and the problem.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean with "redudandant" and "code duplication". That `index` apears twice in `index.index` ? You can overload `operator[]` and provide `begin` and `end` such that `for(auto i : index.index){` is written as `for (auto i : index) {`. Is it that what you are looking for?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, yes this is my point, but `for (auto i : index)` is not the only way to use index. Mostly it is used in context like `index.begin()` , `index.end()` which are passed to algorithms which don't accept ranges (I need execution policies). Is there a transparent way to handle index to algorithm which requires iterator? (2) And, is the Index2 the best solution here? Would you use such approach or would your prefer another one?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I've updated the question to make it more specific of the required interface and functionality.

Comment: The *best* approach is to use a database.  Change your data organization to model a relational database.  If you can't use a database, at least you can use some of the organization principles.  For example use `std::vector` to store the data.  Use `std::map<key-type, vector-index>`  The map will allow you to sort the data without changing the vector, a.k.a. index table.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, the application works with large amount of data (many gigabytes of text), large indexes and extensively uses GPU. With this I want to stress that care about performance is not a “premature optimization” here, so database is under a big question and maps are out of the question; they not only lead to memory fragmentation and performance impact, they are hard to pass to GPU. I am not an expert in database architectures, but “use DB” always sounds to me like “use global variables” in this way or another. My goal is fast, flexible and compact code.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, as an extra point, my question about specific problem, or better to say, specific pattern. The question how to solve this and, possible similar problems when they come in code in most straightforward way without adding new unnecessary modules and blocks, keeping the system as simple as possible, following the Occam's razor principle with the system constructed "*constructed with the smallest possible set of elements*". I am not sure that in OOP the answer "put in some bag (database)" is the best solution while it comes to decomposition and reusability.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, and I forgot to mention that, of course, this is a very simplified example for sake of small code size. Of course, the real code uses vector to store the data which is really set of lexem ids, not the text itself. It is always hard to find balance between details to be provided and length of the question.