# Is it false positive here: warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, temporary-objects, reference-binding

In the following code:

```
#include <execution>
#include <vector>

template<typename T> 
class Index {
public:    
    const std::string& text;
    const std::vector<T>& index;

    decltype(index.begin())& begin() { return index.begin(); } // No warning
    decltype(index.end())&   end()   { return index.end(); }  // No warning

    const decltype(index.cbegin())& begin() const { return index.cbegin(); }
    const decltype(index.cend())&   end() const { return index.cend(); }
};

int main()
{
}
```

Visual Studio 2022 (recent version) gives warnings:

> warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary

twice for every line with `decltype`. At the same time [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9Y1sGTazz) with the same configuration doesn't.

Is this false-positive warnings or the code should be fixed?

My intention in the code to return const reference to const iterators. Is this correct approach/syntax for this?

**Update**

Interesting thing that for non-const version (just added to the source code above) none of compilers give a warning, although we still have the same reference to local copy.

**Update 2**

I realized that actually I did need these two recent members and the only thing I needed is to have:

```
template<typename T> 
class Index {
public:    
    const std::string& text;
    const std::vector<T>& index;

    decltype(index.begin()) begin() const { return index.begin(); }
    decltype(index.end())   end()   const { return index.end(); }  

};
```

This cover all the needs in the client code. So, I was just lucky trying `const` as a type of returning value with the reference; as the result I got this warning and got understanding of it with help of all participants of the thread.

Comment: The warning is correct, `index.cbegin()` is a temporary and you return a reference to it. _My intention in the code to return const reference to const iterators._  -- Why would you want to do this? Return your iterators by value.

Comment: @chrysante, performance consideration for the cases when iterator size if bug enough to have impact. This is not a "premature optimization", this is the question how to handle such situations when it comes to high frequency interactions in this part of code.

Comment: Why would you expect an iterator to be big? I would expect it to be a something like a pointer.

Comment: Returning a pointer or reference to a local variable is **always** a mistake.  If there's a bug here it's in the compiler that *didn't* flag it.

Comment: Between copy elision and move semantics, there's hardly any overhead involved with returning by value these days.

Comment: @jabaa, in this particular case, of course. The code uses these iterators only for the sake of simplicity. What if more sophisticated iterators or another data structure is used? What should be the common approach? I remember in new versions of C++ there is some technique which helps to automatically choose passing by reference/value, but I can't remember it now. Interesting, does it take into account such situations?

Comment: @MarkRansom, why do you consider something in this example a local variable? To be more specific "local to what"? Would it be local to `begin`\`end` functions, I would agree. If it is "local" to `Index` objects, what is the concern as long as `Index` objects live longer than client code?

Comment: `index.cbegin()` returns an iterator, that is destroyed at the end of the function `begin`. It's local to that function. The same for `index.cend()`.

Comment: @MarkRansom, on the "copy elision and move semantics...". Makes sense. Thank you. So, would removing `&` be the best solution here or there are some other concerns?

Comment: @jabaa, ops. This made the whole point. With my habit of using references I missed that STL's `begin()`/`end()` return new iterators, not references. Thank you. Now I got the point.

Comment: @DamirTenishev • C++ is hard.  I've certainly had my own "doh!" moments with it, and I expect I will for years to come.

Comment: @AhmedAEK, I can compare with it which is enough for `end()`; algorithms can copy it to non-constant iterators and use them. So, I don't see any issue with const iterator.

Comment: Why would you return a const iterator to copy it again? I thought this is about performance. Remember, the function already returns a copy.

Comment: You'll run into trouble though if you use `auto` to assign the return value of a const iterator.

Comment: @jabaa, the interesting thing that for non-const version (just added to the source code above) none of compilers give a warning, although we still have the same reference to local copy.

Comment: @MarkRansom, just to make you notice the comment. Just updated the question with non-const members, for which none of compilers give a warning, although we still have the same reference to local copy. Is it "another case" or still the question to compilers?

Comment: I find this to be a common misconception, and a common mistake when learning C++: a belief that references are a secret sauce for dramatic performance improvement, so references get sprayed into every available corner and crevice. This is not true. Using class members as references, in this manner, will eventually end in tears. In any case, ths compiler warning is correct, and makings thing const or not const will make no difference, whatsoever. It'll still be undefined behavior when a reference to  a temporary object that gets destroyed at function exit gets returned from the function.

Comment: Firstly, `std::vector::cbegin()` and `cend()` both return by value, which semantically involves a temporary (as the warning says).   Second, I disagree with your claim that returning a reference to an iterator is not premature optimisation - by design, iterators are typically small objects that are inexpensive to copy and (with modern - post 2017 - C++ compilers) temporaries will often be elided anyway.  Premature optimisation describes effort to optimise that is based on an assertion that it is beneficial but without any actual evidence (e.g. analysis/testing/profiling) there is a benefit.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I would only say that using C++ more than 30 years I got different experience. But this will start a holy war, let's stay on the question only.

Comment: @Peter, I see where you coming from. As I stated in the comments above, I used iterators just for a sake of simplicity and example. My question was about syntax to know how to handle this in other situations when the object could be bigger or couldn't be copy-constucted at all.  I met the warning with exactly this code and shown it, in reality the class could be different and I just want to learn the trap, nothing more.

Comment: @Peter, on premature optimization, how you know if I have actual evidence? There is no information about it and I really consider adding it to any such question excessive. Let me stress that my question about syntax and potential problem, not about the best architecture for this specific case.

Comment: Funny thing here. In this topic a lot of people participated even after the answer was given by at least three of them while in the very close question [The best place to store index to data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77808469/the-best-place-to-store-index-to-data) which was the "root cause" of this question only two people participated. What makes from so much different? :)

Comment: As a second thought, is there a way to return not iterators, but the `begin`/`end` functions themselves to make it even more transparent?

Comment: @DamirTenishev This question is very simple. The one you linked is quite difficult, involving ranges and metaprogramming.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, thank for pinpoint, I suspected that unnecessary usage of ranges will complicate the question, just didn't find a way to simplify the code. Will do tomorrow.

Comment: @DamirTenishev   You're the one who made a claim of a cost benefit, without evidence.   Most people who have evidence would actually cite it.    Particularly in a case like this in which C++ standard iterators are *designed* in a way to mitigate such cost  (operations on those iterators like incrementing or dereferencing may be a different story, but returning a reference to an iterator from a function does not address cost of those operations).

Comment: @Peter, makes sense, point taken. The only thing I want to stress to explain my approach is that I want to learn the language way to handle things in case it is needed in other cases where the returned object much more complex and weighty or can't be construction-copied at all. So, my intention was to understand what is the potential issue or trap here and I succeeded with this with help of all people involved.

Comment: @DamirTenishev   Might have been better if you had said that instead.   People here are more open to people demonstrating effort to learn, rather than making unsupported claims about performance.    Just be aware it is easy, when learning, to make mistakes - and people with experience to spot your mistakes aren't always the most tactful in pointing that out - particularly in a written form.

Comment: @Peter, I am not sure we are on the same page. In the comments above I stated first "The code uses these iterators only for the sake of simplicity. What if more sophisticated iterators or another data structure is used? What should be the common approach?". So I stressed both that I am showing very simplified code which can't be replaced by a real code since it would be too large and complex for question (and the answer from *Yksisarvinen* confirms that) and that I want to learn in advance how to handle this. Would you like to chat privately on this so that I could learn better questioning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a false positive, and you can reproduce it on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nzebrfsjE) if you instantiate the class template:

```cpp
template class Index<int>;
```

MSVC gives you the warning you've already posted, and GCC gives you

```
<source>:10:72: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
   10 |     const decltype(index.cbegin())& begin() const { return index.cbegin(); }
      |                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

The issue is that `index.cbegin()` returns an iterator by value, not by reference.
The return type is `const std::vector::const_iterator&`, and this `const&` binds to a temporary `const_iterator` object.

#### Note on performance considerations

You've said that you're returning the iterator by `const&` because

> performance consideration for the cases when iterator size is big enough to have impact.

This is not something you should worry about.
Iterators are a generalization of pointers ([[iterator.requirements.general] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements.general#1)) and are meant to be small, lightweight objects that can be passed around by value cheaply.
If an iterator is expensive to pass around, that's a design issue with the iterator.

Note that standard library algorithms in `<algorithm>` also take iterators by value.

#### Note on language evolution

If [P2748: Disallow Binding a Returned Glvalue to a Temporary](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2748r2.html) is accepted into the C++26 standard (and the consensus is overall favorable), then your code will be ill-formed.

In other words, it likely won't even compile in C++26.

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning the thing you have by reference, you're returning the results of a function call.

That the function happens to be on a method you have a reference to is irrelevant.

```
const std::vector<T>& index;


const decltype(index.cbegin())& begin() const { return index.cbegin(); }
```

The solution is to just not return references -- just return copies.   Iterators should be cheap to copy.